# how to sample vec4 texture2d instead of sampler2d texture

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to make a blur effect on my modified texture2d object but how do I sample the texture2d object without using the texture2D function?
For example, to make the sampler2d baseTexture  blurry, I could sum up the samples with the following code:

```
void main(){
    vec4 baseColor = texture2D( baseTexture, vUv); 
    vec4 sum = vec4( 0.0 );
    sum += texture2D( baseTexture, vec2( vUv.x, vUv.y - 4.0 * v ) ) * 0.051;
    sum += texture2D( baseTexture, vec2( vUv.x, vUv.y - 3.0 * v ) ) * 0.0918;
    ...etc
    gl_FragColor =  sum
}
```

How would I be able to sample from the baseColor instead of the baseTexture?
Thanks,

Jim

Comment: What do you mean sample from the baseColor? Your baseColor is one of the texture samples but to have a blur effect you need multiple samples as you are doing already by retrieving a different samples from the texture. Try to explain a bit on what you wish to achieve, maybe some pseudo code...

Comment: is it possible to sample from the texture sample? Say, I first set baseColor = texture2D(baseTexutre,vUv) * vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0) and then blur new redish baseColor texture.

Comment: A texture sample is a vector, nothing more. It holds only a few floating values which can represent a color. A texture sampler on the other hand can retrieve any pixel from the texture. So, no, you can not "sample from a texture sample" as your sample does not contain any data that can be sampled.

Comment: OK, thanks for clearing this up. Normally, how would you apply multiple effects like changing the color then taking that result and applying blur? Thanks.

Comment: Like so? :   
vec4 sum = vec4( 0.0 );
    vec4 sample;
    
    sample = texture2D( baseTexture, vec2( vUv.x, vUv.y - 4.0 * v ) ) * 0.051;
    sample = vec4(sample.r/3.0 + sample.g/3.0 + sample.b/3.0);
    sum += sample
    sample = texture2D( baseTexture, vec2( vUv.x, vUv.y - 3.0 * v ) ) * 0.0918;
    ...